# Mutual information and chain rule

Tags: information-theory, entropy

I'm having difficulty proving the below statement. It looks trivial but I don't know how to treat the term $XY$.

$I(XY ;Z) = I(X;Z)+ I(Y ;Z|X)$

How is it different form $I(X,Y ;Z) = I(X;Z)+ I(Y ;Z|X)$?

Comment: Your first equation is incorrect if you are referring to the product of $X$ and $Y$. Your second equation with the comma is the correct chain rule of mutual information.

Answer (score 1):

You can write:
\begin{align*}
I(X,Y;Z)&=H(X,Y)-H(X,Y|Z)\\
&=H(X)+H(Y|X)-(H(X|Z)+H(Y|X,Z))\\
&=(H(X)-H(X|Z))+(H(Y|X)-H(Y|X,Z))\\
&=I(X;Z)-I(Y;Z|X)
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you make the last two lines work?